# Why I can't purchase the Nissan Skyline GT-R V-spec (1999) for Off-roading?

Tags: need-for-speed-payback

I'm trying to purchase the R34 Skyline for Off-roading, but is not listed on the Off-road dealership for some reason.

[The wiki](https://nfs.fandom.com/wiki/Nissan_Skyline_GT-R_V-Spec_(R34)#Need_for_Speed:_Payback) says that the R34 is available for Drag, Off-road and Race, but I only got the Race (Eddie's) and Drag (purchased) versions:

[image]

Why I can't get the Skyline GT-R V-spec (1999) for Off-roading? How can I get it?

(Please note that I have already finished the main game story)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact of the matter is that the wikia article you saw is wrong. The NISSAN Skyline GT-R V-spec 1999 is not available for purchase in the Offroad class. [It's only available in Drag, Drift and Race](https://www.ea.com/games/need-for-speed/need-for-speed-payback/news/nfs-payback-car-list).

In a [different page](https://nfs.fandom.com/wiki/Need_for_Speed:_Payback/Cars) of the Wikia you can find the classes the car is made available in. The 6 icons on the top represent which classes the car is available in, the third is Offroad and it's grayed-out, not available.

[image]

You were, understandably, confused as the [1999 GT-R](https://nfs.fandom.com/wiki/Nissan_Skyline_GT-R_V-Spec_(R34)) page of the Wikia (used for your screenshot) displays that it is available in the Offroad class via the third icon is filled-in when it should not be.

[image]

In fact, there price of the car depicted in your screenshot ($88,700) is actually the value of the 1993 NISSAN Skyline which is available for Offroad purchase! Confusing, right?

[image]

In short, the NFS wikia is inaccurate and you can't buy it. Sorry.